# How to show the static blocks in Magento 2?

Tags: php, magento2

I'm creating a magento 2 theme.
I want to display the custom blocks on the cms homepage.

I want to know to show the static blocks in phtml and xml layout, cms page contents

How can I do?

Comment: I want to know to show the static blocks in phtml and xml layout, cms page contents.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Please try to use below codes.

In Phtml File:

```
<?php echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('Magento\Cms\Block\Block')->setBlockId('block_identifier')->toHtml();?>
```

in CMS Content:

```
{{block class="Magento\\Cms\\Block\\Block" block_id="block_identifier"}}
```

In Xml File:

```
<referenceContainer name="content">
    <block class="Magento\Cms\Block\Block" name="block_identifier">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="block_id" xsi:type="string">block_identifier</argument>
        </arguments>
    </block>
</referenceContainer>
```

Comment: Using Magento 2.0.2. For testing purposes, I have inserted provided above xml in to the product page "Custom Layout Update", and provided php block in to the `app/design/frontend/Magento/<Vendor>/<theme>/Magento_Catalog/templates/product/view/details.phtm`. I still not able to see this block. Did I do anything wrong?

Comment: I needed to set other parameters as well like this ```<?php echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('vendor\module\Block\BlockClass')->setName('name')->setTemplate('vendor_module::template.phtml')->toHtml(); ?>```

Answer (score 1):

The above is correct, additionally, the xml file for the homepage is `cms_index_index.xml` inside of the `Magento_Cms` folder (and this should go in your own package/theme folder, not in `Magento/blank` or `app/code`).

Just put the above xml code inside the `<body>` tag in that file, depending on the cache settings you may need to clear them to see the adjustments.

Answer (score 1):

none of these work for putting static blocks via default.xml Please remit proper examples. In 2.0.7 When I apply to my theme the following after creating a static block in administration named socialimg / socialimg as block identifier nothing shows up. nor even in memory. not even a search of exception.log or system.log

```
    <page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceContainer name="header.panel">
            <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Html\Links" name="header.links">
                <arguments>
                    <argument name="css_class" xsi:type="string">header links</argument>
                </arguments>
            </block>
        </referenceContainer>
<referenceBlock name="socialimg1">
    <block class="Magento\Cms\Block\Block" name="socialimg">
        <arguments>
          <argument name="block_id" xsi:type="string">socialimg</argument>
        </arguments>
    </block>
</referenceBlock>
        <referenceBlock name="logo">
            <arguments>
                <argument name="logo_img_width" xsi:type="number">148</argument>
                <argument name="logo_img_height" xsi:type="number">43</argument>
            </arguments>
        </referenceBlock>
        <referenceContainer name="footer">
            <block class="Magento\Store\Block\Switcher" name="store_switcher" as="store_switcher" after="footer_links" template="switch/stores.phtml"/>
        </referenceContainer>
        <referenceBlock name="report.bugs" remove="true"/>
        <move element="copyright" destination="before.body.end"/>
    </body>
</page>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the following code to display the static block in CMS page -

```
{{block class="Magento\\Cms\\Block\\Block" block_id="block_identifier"}}
```

Use the following code to display the static block in phtml file -

```
<?php echo $block->getLayout()->createBlock('Magento\Cms\Block\Block')->setBlockId('block_identifier')->toHtml();?>
```